# Spring Rest API For Mobile Apps - Add Push Notifications

Tags: android, ios, spring, push-notification, spring-rest

I am new to implementing push notifications in Spring and apologise if this question has been asked before.

I am developing a backend Rest API that will be used by iOS and Android app created in React Native. My question is is there a library or something that can make it easy to send the push notification regardless of whether it is iOS or Android or have I got the wrong idea how sending push notifications from the back end works.

Thanks you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) in iOS and Android and use FCM Rest API to send push notifications to users.